# Central limit theorem with multiple means and variances

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

How does the Central limit theorem work when there are multiple random variables, each one with a different mean and variance?

For example, let $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ be random variables that represent the income of three shops **per day**. Each $X_i$ is independent of each other and are normally distributed with $\mu_1 = \$1500000, \mu_2=\$2500000, \mu_3 =\$2000000, \sigma_1=\$300000,\sigma_2=\$150000$ and $\sigma_3=\$200000$. What is the probability that the income of the three shops during 5 days is greater than $\$29720000$?

My thoughts: $\sigma_\bar{X}^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sigma^2_{X_i}=1.525\times10^{11}$ and $\mu_\bar{X}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\mu_{X_i}=6000000$

Normalizing, I have $\frac{29720000-6000000}{390512.484}=60.74$

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It is not a CLT problem. You are supposed to use $5$ days, so there are $15$ random variables $X_{1,1}$ up to $X_{1,5}$, and similarly for the $X_2$'s and $X_3$'s. For the means multiply by $5$, for the variance add the $15$ variances.

Comment: I don't understand what must be done with the 15 random variables and all the means and variances. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: let $Y$~$N(\mu_{X_{1,1}}+...+\mu_{X_{3,5}}, \sigma^2_{X_{1,1}}+...+\sigma^2_{X_{3,5}})$, so $Y$~$N(5(1500000+2500000+2000000) , 5(300000^2+150000^2 + 200000^2))$, so $Y$~$N(30000000, 7.625\times 10^{11}))$

Comment: The procedure is now right.